# Shortcut key to go to last opened panel (dev panel) in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a shortcut key to switch between the Chrome dev panels while you are working there like the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> functionality for Windows?

If not, then is it possible to configure it or write a plugin for this purpose?

Also, I know that we have this shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to move between the panels but how to get to the last working panel with keyboard shortcut key?

For example:
You want to switch between two panels:- sources

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. There is already a shortcut to open the Dev Tools without indicating the panel you want - and it will open the last panel that was active. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: nope..
I was asking how to switch between the panels like we can switch between the windows with ALT + TAB?

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want. It's probably best if you present the use case step by step.

Comment: @Xan I was asking how to switch between the dev panels while you are working there like ALT + TAB for windows. You got my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Dev Tools, there's a handy Shortcuts reference, accessible by going to Settings (gear icon).

Of note:

> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> Go to the panel to the left/right
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> Go back/forward in panel history

Comment: I was searching for this: Ctrl + Alt + [ / Ctrl + Alt + ]
Thanks for your time  :)

Comment: I couldn't find that shortcut reference there

Comment: @soredive I checked, it's still there in latest release Chrome version. Make sure you're clicking the right gear icon to go to DevTools' overall setting menu.